# How to access Json data's

Tags: json, flutter, api, flutter-listview

I have some Json data. But i cannot access its inside without write first key name.
Json data's link is https://api.genelpara.com/embed/borsa.json I want to put them to Listview. How can I put them? If I write like code , I can access only 'satis' key and value and display on Listview but I want to access 'ALGYO' key as a value and show on Listview.

`child: Center(child: Text(' ${snapshot.data['ALGYO']['satis']}'))`

Comment: there is no data with the key ``ALGYO`` !!!

Comment: can I access  ALGYO key as a value?

Comment: there is no value as ``ALGYO`` in the JSON !!

Comment: sorryyy!! I edited api link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `keys` from your JSON (like `ALGYO` and `ARZUM`) and then you can access data inside. Try the following code, you can easily add `alis` and `degisim` where you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ListView',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final data = {
    'ALGYO': {'satis': "20.18", 'alis': "20.16", 'degisim': "-1,46"},
    'ARZUM': {'satis': "17.68", 'alis': "17.68", 'degisim': "-20,93"},
    'ACSEL': {'satis': "16.41", 'alis': "16.41", 'degisim': "-2,32"},
    'ADANA': {'satis': "12.19", 'alis': "12.19", 'degisim': "0,00"},
    'ADBGR': {'satis': "8.62", 'alis': "8.62", 'degisim': "0,00"},
    'ADEL': {'satis': "0.0476", 'alis': "0.0476", 'degisim': "-1,04"},
    'ADESE': {'satis': "1.2", 'alis': "1.2", 'degisim': "-1,64"},
    'ADNAC': {'satis': "2.09", 'alis': "2.09", 'degisim': "0,00"},
    'AEFES': {'satis': "21.46", 'alis': "21.46", 'degisim': "-1,29"},
    'AFYON': {'satis': "3.63", 'alis': "3.63", 'degisim': "-0,82"},
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListView'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          // this will be the key for the current item
          String key = data.keys.elementAt(index);
          // here you can see how to access "satis" under
          // current key
          return ListTile(
              title: Text("$key"), subtitle: Text(data[key]!["satis"]!));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I convert api data as final data which you show